# Mouse scroll doesn't work while moving pointer on VMWare Workstation with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mouse, vmware, scrolling

Odd bug - Scrolling works somewhat smoothly as one would expect, however while moving the mouse-pointer it completely stops scrolling and locks in place.

I have read bugs regarding having a non-default input source. I use the nordic layout(Danish), but I've tried switching it back to default(English - USA), however this had no effect.

Comment: I have exactly this problem, did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: Sorry, I did not.

Comment: Maybe a bit late, but this helped me out: https://superuser.com/questions/1257137/scroll-wheel-not-working-when-mouse-is-moving

Comment: That option does not seem to be available in the Player version of VMWare.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember where I found it but someone solved that by

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput && sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-evdev
```

which also worked for me :)